# Lodash set not applying update to array

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash

I am trying to update the 'mobileNumber' field of all elements in an array.
I have tried the following suggestions here on StackOverflow, but none seem to update the field in the array.

```
_.each(results, function(item) {
  _.set(item, 'mobileNumber', 2);
});

const formattedResults = _.each(results, function(item) {
  _.set(item, 'mobileNumber', 2);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT : It turns out in Typescript that even assigning my original array to a new array using let, somehow kept the new array readonly too.

I ended up using lodash _clone, before setting the value, and then the update worked...

```
let formattedResults = _.map(results, _.clone);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is actually correct check here https://jsbin.com/fiyinahovi/edit?js,console

```
let results = [{mobileNumber: 1}, {mobileNumber: 3}, {mobileNumber: 7}]
_.each(results, function(item) {
  _.set(item, 'mobileNumber', 2);
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Ok strange, I'll need to determine what's different in my source array then. There are no sub objects or anything. Thanks

Comment: you also do not need to use lodash you can do it simply by
results.forEach((item) => item.mobileNumber = 2)

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me for asking but why the need for `_.set`? Usually you want to utilize `set` in scenarios where the property you want to change is passed as string etc. Looking at your code you have `mobileNumber` set/hardcoded inside of the `_.each` body ... or this is just for example purposes?

Because otherwise it is more concise (and with no need for lodash) with just:

```js
let results = [{mobileNumber: 1, foo: 2}, {mobileNumber: 3}, {mobileNumber: 7}]

results.forEach(x => x.mobileNumber = 2)

console.log(results)
```

Comment: Same problem as with jQuery, people learn a framework then think the only way to solve problems is using that framework.